# Torsion-free divisible group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I have some confusion.

Let $G$ be a torsion-free divisible abelian group. Then, $G$ is a $\mathbb Q$-vector space. If $G$ has a finite dimension as a vector space then can we write $G$ as a finite direct sum of copies of $\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: I think you mean divisible groups? Torsion free groups needn't have a rational vector space strcture.

Comment: @ Alex, thanks $G$ is divisible. I just edit my question.

Comment: Yes, we can, if it has finite dimension.  If it has infinite dimension, it is still a direct sum, but there will be infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Steve, is that case even if $G$ has finite rational rank.

Answer (score 9):

You are correct. Since $G$ (a torsion-free divisible group) is divisible given any $y\in G$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ there exists a solution $x$ to $mx=y$. Since $G$ is torsion-free this solution is unique. Thus, we can define $\displaystyle \frac{1}{m}y:=x$. One then shows that this defines a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space structure on $G$, and so $G\cong \mathbb{Q}^{\oplus\lambda}$ for some cardinal $\lambda$. Saying that the dimension of $G$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is finite is just saying that $\lambda$ is finite, and so we get exactly what you wanted.

Comment: @ Alex Thanks, got it.